# How can I control the order of entries in the YASnippet menu?

Tags: yasnippet

I use YASnippets for everything and often use them through YASnippet menu. For any given major-mode, I use the `.yas-parents` file and put the directory/names in the order that I want them. But they appear in the menus in an order which seems random.

Having control over the order in the menus is important as we want to see what is more important at the top of the menu and sometime want to have related topics next to one another in the menu.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to "sort" the entries in `yas-minor-mode-map`.

Here is a sample demo for `org-mode` yasnippet snippets.

**Before**
[image: Yasnippets for org-mode]

**After**

[image: Yasnippets for org-mode (re-arranged)]

While visiting an `org` file, do `M-:` and copy paste the following snippet at minibuffer.  It will sort the menu entries based on *the length of the name of snippet*

```lisp
(let* ((keymap (lookup-key yas-minor-mode-map [menu-bar yasnippet org-mode]))
       (entries (cdr keymap)))
  ;; (setcdr keymap (nreverse entries))
  (setcdr keymap
      (sort entries
        (lambda (entry1 entry2)
          (< (length (nth 2 entry1))
             (length (nth 2 entry2))))))
  keymap)
```

You can fill in the value of the vector

```lisp
[menu-bar yasnippet org-mode]
```

by doing `C-h k Menu Bar -> Yasnippet -> ... and some snippet entry` and you will see some text in the `*Help*` buffer like what you see below.  Note down the symbols that you see at the beginning after stripping the `<>`.

```
<menu-bar> <yasnippet> <org-mode> <dot> runs the command (lambda nil
(interactive) (yas--expand-or-visit-from-menu 'org-mode "dot")) (found
in yas-minor-mode-map), which is an interactive Lisp function.

(anonymous)

Not documented.
```

---

As an additional note, if `Emacs`refreshes the snippet menu and you lose the order of entries, then you may have to hook the snippet I shared to one of the "hook"s (Do `M-x apropos RET menu-bar hook`)

---

If you are comfortable with `elisp`, you can do `M-x pp-eval-expression` on

```lisp
(lookup-key yas-minor-mode-map [menu-bar yasnippet org-mode])
```

and you can roll out your own menu entries in the order you want.

Comment: Lots of good pointers in here. I'll experiment to see what works best for me. Will follow up later.